# How find $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(ka)}{k^2}$ using Fourier?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $$f(x)= \begin{cases}\frac{x}{a} & \text{ if } 0\leq x\leq a \\ \frac{2\pi - x}{2\pi - a} &\text{ if } a \leq x \leq 2\pi\end{cases}$$
and prolonged over $\mathbb R$ by $2\pi-$periodicity.

1) Compute it's Fourier coeficients.

2) Deduce $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(ak)}{k^2}$

**Attempt**

1) $$c_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}\mathrm d x=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^a\frac{x}{a}e^{-inx}\mathrm d x+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_a^{2\pi}\frac{2\pi-x}{2\pi -a}e^{-inx}\mathrm d x.$$
Integrating by part, we get
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^a\frac{x}{a}e^{-inx}\mathrm d x=\frac{e^{-ian}(1+ian)-1}{2\pi an^2}$$
and
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_a^{2\pi}\frac{2\pi-x}{2\pi-a}e^{-inx}\mathrm d x=\frac{e^{-ian}(ian-2i\pi n+1)-1}{2\pi(2\pi-a)n^2}.$$

2) I don't see how to do it. I know that $$f(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}c_ke^{-ikx}$$
for all $x\in [0,2\pi]$, but I don't know how to conclude.

Comment: Potentially helpful: we can write
$$
c_n = \frac{e^{-ian}(1+ian)-1}{2\pi an^2}  + 
\frac{e^{-ian}(ian-2i\pi n+1)-1}{2\pi(2\pi-a)n^2} = \\
\frac{e^{-ian}(1+ian)-1}{2\pi an^2}  - 
\frac{e^{-ian}(ian-2i\pi n+1)-1}{2\pi(a - 2\pi)n^2} =\\
\frac{1}{2 \pi n^2} \left[
\frac{e^{-ian}(1+ian)-1}{a}  - 
\frac{e^{-ian}(ian-2i\pi n+1)-1}{a - 2\pi} 
 \right] = 
\frac{1}{2 \pi n^2} \left[
e^{-ian}\left(\frac{1+ian}{a}  - 
\frac{ian-2i\pi n+1}{a - 2\pi}\right) + 
\left(
\frac{1}{a - 2\pi} - 
\frac{1}{a}
\right)
 \right]
$$